# how to I observe cell accessory Type UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark is checked or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

How do I observe cell accessory Type `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` is checked or not?

In my app I added `UITableView` in a `UIAlertView`. I also used

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

In my tableView, i have 9 rows. When the user taps on first row then all rows become checked except second row. The user can check any row/rows as he wishes. When the user taps on the second row then only the second row is checked.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Just check the tapped row?

Comment: i want to check as above description...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answer of @dasblinkenlight is certainly more elegant, it might be too advanced for you.

The essence is to keep track of which cells are checked and which are unchecked. Whenever something changes, reload the table view to updated the checkmarks.

You need to create your own variable to track this. A bitmap is very economical and elegant, but it might be difficult to understand and not scalable to a large number of rows. Alternatively, you could use an array.

```
NSMutableArray *checkedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                   nil];
```

To change a row given the index path:

```
[checkedArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row 
                        withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]; //add

[checkedArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row 
                        withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]; //remove
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` make sure you set the accessory explicitly:

```
if ([[checkedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryTypeCheckmark;
} 
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryTypeNone;
}
```

Comment: Mundi - thank u so much  4 help me .. :) i also know that it hard for multiple row.. u hv idea for multiple row..???

Comment: The above works well for multiple rows. Set the BOOL to YES or NO as desired.

Comment: yup i got above code is work..but consider that i have 1000 rows then above code is also worked but it not proper idea for this logic :)

Comment: Sure it is. Just loop, and you will end up with just a few lines of code.

Comment: Mundi- okay..thanks...i have also que. :( how can i get checked row/rows in AlertView  clickedButtonAtIndex (when button pressed), i know that i need to create cell and indexPath and also save/add it. i tried but not get  it :( plz help me one more time :) thanks

Comment: In `clickedButtonAtIndex` just check your array.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of items is so small, you can model the checked/unchecked state with a single integer and bitmasks. Use the lower nine bits of the number to indicate a checked/unchecked state:

```
// Add an instance variable to your view controller
// Initialize to 0 in the designated initializer
NSUInteger checkedFlags;

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *res = ... // Dequeue the cell and so on

    res.accessoryType = (checkedFlags & (1 << indexPath.row))
    ?    UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
    :    UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    ... // The rest of the method
}
```

Here is how you check/uncheck/toggle an individual row: in the `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` of your delegate, do one of these:

```
checkedFlags |= (1 << indexPath.row); // Check
checkedFlags &= ~(1 << indexPath.row); // Uncheck
checkedFlags ^= (1 << indexPath.row); // Toggle
```

If you want to check/uncheck multiple rows at once, mask with a number composed of the bits corresponding to rows being checked/unchecked in the binary form For example, the number that has bits 2..8 set is `0x01FC0`.

```
checkedFlags |= 0x1FC0; // Check rows #3 through #9
```

Don't forget to call `reloadData` after manipulating the `checkedFlags` variable.

Comment: This will not work. If the user unchecks a checked cell and the cell is dequeued, it will still show the check mark. You need an `else` clause to set the `accessoryType` to `UITableViewCellAccessoryTypeNone`.

Comment: @Mundi I assumed the `...` code would bring the cell to a neutral state, but you're right, I should have spelled it out explicitly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){

}
else{ 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, but I've had a lot of luck maintaining a NSMutableIndexSet instance, and adding / removing indexes for checked / unchecked rows.

The key methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSInteger index = indexPath.row;
    cell.accessoryType = ([self.selectedRowsIndexSet containsIndex:index]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d",index];

    return cell;
}
```

This is fairly straight-foward - check to see if the index is selected and set the accessory accordingly.

For a multi-select (i.e. any call can be selected) implementation of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger index = indexPath.row;
    if ([self.selectedRowsIndexSet containsIndex:index])
        [self.selectedRowsIndexSet removeIndex:index];
    else
        [self.selectedRowsIndexSet addIndex:index];

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ indexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Just add the index, reload the table. For a single select it's pretty quick too

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger oldIndex = [self.selectedRowsIndexSet firstIndex];
    NSInteger newIndex = indexPath.row;
    [self.selectedRowsIndexSet removeIndex:oldIndex];
    [self.selectedRowsIndexSet addIndex:newIndex];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ indexPath, [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:oldIndex inSection:0] ]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Can of course get more complicated with more sections, whether selections in some sections depend on selections in others, and so on. I've been using per-section arrays of index sets for the former and then various complex logic involving the underlying data model for the latter. But keeping the basic table view interaction at the level of just querying an index set helps keep these methods pretty short and readable.

Comment: Take a look, let me know if that helps.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how you can tell which rows are checked and which aren't? You check to see if the index set contains their index, like `[self.selectedRowsIndexSet containsIndex:indexPath.row]`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I really need help about checked,Could you help me?

Comment: @MacGeek you should ask a specific question, see http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx for details on how to ask

Comment: Thanks again but right now I don't have authority to ask question here